# Blank page when deploying react made by vite to github pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite

I have been struggling a lot to tackle this problem but still I cannot find the right answer.

When I try to deploy my react app made by vite to github pages, there is a blank page. But locally, it works perfect.

[This](https://soheum.github.io/) is the page I have deployed.

And this is my [github repository.](https://github.com/soheum/soheum.github.io)

I've already checked several options:

- my base is set to  `base: "{soheum.github.io}"` in `vite.config.ts` file
- tried deploying with `vite.config.ts` and `vite.config.js`
- in my `package.json` I have included `"homepage": "https://soheum.github.io/soheum.github.io"`

And there is this error in my console log:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Are there any ways to fix this..?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

edit: Solved: github pages deployment was targeting main branch with pure react code, instead of gh-pages branch that only contais the "dist" folder contents. Just go to repository settings, Pages, point to your gh-pages branch.

Let me make this easy for you:

1. cd to root of your project;
2. run:
   `npm i gh-pages --save-dev`
3. add the deploy script inside your package.json:

   "scripts": {
   "dev": "vite",
   ...
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
   },
4. run `npm run build` if you haven't done yet, so you generate a `dist` folder with your build
5. run `npm run deploy`

this will create a `gh-pages` branch with only ur build, and all you need to do now is go to your Repository SETTINGS, open `Pages` section on the left, and configure it to point to the GH-PAGES branch instead of the MAIN branch.

---

Facing same problem but with (“text/html”)...

A module loading from “https://gxxxxxx.github.io/src/main.tsx” was blocked due to disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).